# How to unacknowledge a message and send it back to the queue in JMS?

Tags: jms, message, consuming

Using JMS once I read/consume a message from queue I want to redeliver the same message back to queue because I want to stop processing for a while. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

To cancel unacknowledged messages back to the queue you can simply close your JMS consumer. If you're using AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE mode on your JMS session you won't be able to cancel the messages back to the queue as they'll be acknowledged automatically.

If you're using a transacted JMS session you can simply call `rollback()` on the session.

Comment: I am using DefaultMessageListenerContainer.                     
DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();     container.setSessionTransacted(true); How can I call a rollback here? Can you pls help.

Comment: How to rollback a transaction using the Spring JMS API is really a different question than the one you originally asked. I recommend you ask a *new* question about this and if my answer addressed your original question mark it as correct to help other users who may have this same question in the future. Thanks!